# What is the difference between impertinent and impudent?

Tags: vocabulary

Do impertinent and impudent have different meanings?
What is the difference between impertinent and impudent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are synonyms with very close, essentially the same meaning:

**Impertinent** means: Exceeding the limits of propriety or good manners; improperly forward or bold. (The etymology is "not pertinent", "does not hold" from Latin.)

**Impudent** means the same thing:  Offensively bold or disrespectful. (The etymology is "not pudent", "not ashamed" from Latin.)

Comment: So they are synonymous. Right?

Comment: Correct, they are.

Answer (score 2):

These words are close synonyms of each other. The Oxford Dictionary Online defines [impertinent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impertinent) as

> Not showing proper respect; rude.

with synonyms *rude, **insolent**, impolite, unmannerly, ill-mannered, bad-mannered, uncivil, discourteous, disrespectful*

and [impudent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/impudent) as

> Not showing due respect for another person; impertinent.

with synonyms ***impertinent, insolent**, cheeky, audacious, brazen, shameless, immodest, pert*

The actual definitions are very similar and **impertinent** actually forms part of this definition of **impudent**. There are, however some subtle differences.

Firstly **impudent** has only one definition but **impertinent** has the secondary definition

> Not pertinent to a particular matter; irrelevant.

This is a much less frequently used meaning but could confuse you if you are not aware of it.

Secondly there is a slight difference in the usage. While both words can describe an attitude of disrespect for a *person* **impertinent** can also describe an attitude of disrepect for an *institution* or other entity. For instance one of the many sample sentences for **impertinent** is

> There's no choice but to speak ill of the dead and ask impertinent questions about the emperor's clothes.

Thirdly the lists of synonyms show a slight difference in style, the list for **impertinence** shows a bias towards seriousness and deliberate challenge but the list for **impudence** indicates a somewhat more light-hearted and more casual intent.

There is a very large overlap in the definition and usage of both words, but only when the disrespect is shown to a person.

When applied to person A's attitude to person B (for example that of a pupil to a teacher) they are virtually identical although **impudent** would be more likely to be used if there was an element of humour in the actions or words of A.

If, on the other hand, A was being disrespectful to an *institution* or *organisation*, particularly if there was a deliberate challenge to its authority, the correct word would **impertinent** as **impudent** is used specifically in relation to people. For instance questions relating to sexual abuse by priests might well have been called **impertinent** by the Church hierarchy in the early stages of the media investigation into it but would not have been called **impudent** as they were directed at the church as an institution.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.